# Retornar os valores mínimos de cada mês em uma nova coluna SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Minha tabela possui as colunas :
DATA (datetime)
PRODUTO (varchar)
PREÇO (float)

Preciso retornar uma consulta dos produtos distintos, onde mostre o valor mínimo de um produto a cada mes, em uma nova coluna como:

```
| PRODUTO | MIN(PREÇO) | janeiro | fevereiro | marco | abril | maio etc...
| cafe    |      1.99  |   2.45  |   1.99    | 2.22  |  3.22 | 2.11
```

Comment: Se entendi a questão pesquise por PIVOT e CASE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Fazendo um pivot com Case , sem teste pode ter erros de síntaxe */

Select produto,
/*extract extrai parte data
  Case faz o tratamento de uma igualdade
  Min agrupa o menor valor*/
       Min(preco) geral,
       Min(Case when Extract(month from data)=1 then preco else null) jan,
       Min(Case when Extract(month from data)=2 then preco else null) fev,
       Min(Case when Extract(month from data)=3 then preco else null) mar,
       Min(Case when Extract(month from data)=4 then preco else null) abr,
       Min(Case when Extract(month from data)=5 then preco else null) mai
/*....*/
From tabela
Where Extract(year from data)=2022
Group by produto;
```

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-extract/

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-group-by/

Answer (score -3):

Para retornar Distinto use o SELECT DISTINCT e para retornar em meses voce precisa criar um CASE

ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,

CASE 
    WHEN DATA > '2022-06-01' AND DATA <'2022-06-30' THEN PRECO
    ELSE ''
END AS JUNHO,

CASE 
    WHEN DATA > '2022-05-01' AND DATA <'2022-05-30' THEN PRECO
    ELSE ''
END AS MAIO,

CASE 
    WHEN DATA > '2022-04-01' AND DATA <'2022-04-30' THEN PRECO
    ELSE ''
END AS ABRIL,

CASE 
    WHEN DATA > '2022-07-01' AND DATA <'2022-07-30' THEN PRECO
    ELSE ''
END AS JULHO


FROM MERCADO;
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DZzT.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Na realidade min(case...) Com group by